# How to add custom html tag in selectize js list

Tags: javascript

How to add custom tag in list of selectize js.
i.e. in list i want to add delete icon(html tag) and on clicking that delete icon that clicked item should get deleted from list.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

first you decide where you want to add list tag that means after a 
 particular li or before then

```
$('your selector').after('<li>

<a class="button"href="javascript:void(0)">Delete</a></li>');
```

then add event Handler.
Remember if you write this code in window load then event handler also write in window on load otherwise you can't get action or document.ready the same as ok.

```
$('body').on('click','#id',function(){
```

//do something what you need like delete list then remember if you remove list then all the attribute including event also remove.

```
$('selector').remove();
```

})